# Sort List<Tuple<int, int>> in-place

Tags: c#, list, sorting

How would I go about sorting in descending order, a `List<Tuple<int, int>>` using the first element of the tuple as the value that determines the order? It has to be in-place and I only know how to do it using LINQ which returns a new list.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You just need to provide an `IComparer<Tuple<int, int>>` or a `Comparison<Tuple<int, int>>` to the `List<T>.Sort` method. The latter is probably easier to specify inline:

```
list.Sort((x, y) => y.Item1.CompareTo(x.Item1));
```

If you want to order by the first value and then the second value, it becomes a bit trickier, but still feasible. For example:

```
list.Sort((x, y) => {
    int result = y.Item1.CompareTo(x.Item1);
    return result == 0 ? y.Item2.CompareTo(x.Item2) : result;
});
```

EDIT: I've now amended the above to sort in descending order. Note that the right way to do this is to reverse the order of the comparison (`y` to `x` instead of `x` to `y`). You must *not* just negate the return value of `CompareTo` - this will fail when `CompareTo` returns `int.MinValue`.

Comment: According to reference source tuples have default comparer that compares by Item1 and then Item2. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/tuple.cs,189

Comment: Even if this is old, I know @JonSkeet is still roaming around: Is `(x, y)` taking 2 items at the same time? So when the first lookup is started, it is taking `list[0]` and `list[1]`? Also: The `ascending order`-comment is commented, but not answered. Is it about the order like `(x, y) or (y, x)` with the followed code?

Comment: @C4ud3x: The `(x, y)` is the parameter list for the lambda expression; the body of the lambda expression compares `x` with `y`. The comment *is* answered, by editing the answer to make the code sort in descending order.

Answer (score 16):

Why not this?

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> list = ...
list = list.OrderBy(i => i.Item1).ToList();
```

Yes, it creates a new list, but I'm just interested - why don't you like this?

---

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> list = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
{
    new Tuple<int,int>(1,1),
    new Tuple<int,int>(0,2),
    new Tuple<int,int>(3,0)
};

list.Sort(Comparer<Tuple<int, int>>.Default);
```

produces:

```
0,2
1,1
3,0
```

And it's in-place, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe because it's not an in-place sort?

Comment: @Martinho: Yes, it is not. I edited my post to make my questions more clear.

Comment: Is `Tuple<T1, T2>` **documented** to sort by `Item1` and then `Item2`?

Comment: @Jon: As far as `Compare<T>.Default` uses `GenericComparer<T>` which calls `CompareTo()`. Appropriate [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782791.aspx) says that "the example defines a .. class that implements the IComparer interface and sorts the `Tuple<T1, T2>` objects in ascending order by the value of their second component **rather than their first component** " so it seems to be implied that the common way is to order by the first component, isn't it?

Comment: @abatishchev: Going by a remark in an example seems somewhat fragile. I think I'd rather use my own comparer than rely on something with only that level of guarantee. Just MHO though.

Comment: @Jon: Agree that's only an assumption based on converse proposition, but I didn't find any well documented in MSDN sorting rules about other classes, do you know any?

Comment: @abatishchev: It's probably not implemented for very many types - numbers, obviously, and strings... although for strings the default doesn't behave in a very obvious way.

Comment: The second half of your divided answer works perfectly. Even with a tuple with 4 items, they are sorted properly using the default comparer, regardless of number of digits or other variations. This should have been the selected answer. Well done!

Answer (score 11):

Now you can use lambda to do it:

```
list = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at the [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) method? You can use an overload that takes a [`Comparison<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) delegate or an [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx):

```
list.Sort((x,y)=> x.Item1.CompareTo(y.Item1));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var listSort = from element in list orderby element.Item1  element.Item2 select element;
```

Comment: You Sir, are a genius!!! I needed to sort a List of IntPoints on the X values.  I was able to easily adapt your example to fit my needs.  This worked really well for me and I am going to add this to the answers in case anyone needs my adapted version.  Thanks so much for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I Needed to sort a List of IntPoints on the X values.  I was able to do this by modifying a previous example.  I am going to put my example here in case anyone needs this example in the future.

```
//Where edges is an unsorted list of edgepoints returned from the C# A.Forge Library
List<IntPoint> edges

//Sorting on the X value of the Intpoint and returning a new List
List<IntPoint> edgesSorted = (from point in edges orderby point.X select point).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with the modern tuple type, which was added in C# 7.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SortTuples
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = new List<(string Name, int Grade)>() 
            {
                ("Patrick", 89),
                ("Lucia", 92),
                ("Veronika", 72),
                ("Robert", 78),
                ("Maria", 65),
                ("Andrea", 51),
                ("Ondrej", 45)
            };

            data.Sort((s1, s2) => s1.Name.CompareTo(s2.Name));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", data));
  
            data.Sort((s1, s2) => s2.Grade.CompareTo(s1.Grade));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", data));
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
$ dotnet run
(Andrea, 51), (Lucia, 92), (Maria, 65), (Ondrej, 45), (Patrick, 89), (Robert, 78), (Veronika, 72)
(Lucia, 92), (Patrick, 89), (Robert, 78), (Veronika, 72), (Maria, 65), (Andrea, 51), (Ondrej, 45)
```