# How to sort a list neither asc or desc but custom

Tags: c#, .net

I am in need of sorting a property in an instance of an object that is inside a list, as like this:

```
    public List<CustomClass> lCustomClasses = new List<CustomClass>();
```

CustomClass has a property MyField that can have one of the following values:

```
    1,2,3
```

I need to sort the list not asc or desc but order by 3,1,2

Any shortcuts to do this without copying to another list?

Comment: You're probably looking at writing your own comparer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird requirement. :)

Anyways, assuming you support only 1, 2 and 3, as others have suggested you can write your own [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx). e.g.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<CustomClass> list = new List<CustomClass>() 
        {
            new CustomClass(){MyField = 3},
            new CustomClass(){MyField = 2},
            new CustomClass(){MyField = 1},
        };
        PrintList(list);
        list.Sort(new CustomClassComparer());
        PrintList(list);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private static void PrintList(List<CustomClass> list)
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            if (item != null)
                Console.WriteLine("MyField: {0}", item.MyField);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("MyField: null");
        }
    }
}

public class CustomClass
{
    public int MyField { get; set; }
}
public class CustomClassComparer : IComparer<CustomClass>
{
    public int Compare(CustomClass x, CustomClass y)
    {
        if (x == null)
        {
            if (y == null)
                return 0;
            return -1;
        }
        if (y == null)
            return 1;

        if (x.MyField == y.MyField)
            return 0;

        if (x.MyField == 2)
            return 1;
        if (x.MyField == 1)
            if (y.MyField == 3)
                return 1;
            else
                return -1;

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can make your `CustomClass` [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Use the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) of List.Sort that takes a custom comparer. See the code sample on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) MSDN page:

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK [`List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx) operates in-place. If you use a custom comparison operator, like suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4668558/520779), you might be able to achieve what you want:

```
lCustomClasses.Sort((x, y) => my_compare(x.MyField, y.MyField));
```