# C# List<Tuple<int,int,int>> to sort only by the tuples T1

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

The list `List<Tuple<int,int,int>>`.

How do I sort it only by the first component of the tuple `T1` from the biggest number to the smallest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort List<Tuple<int, int>> in-place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668525/sort-listtupleint-int-in-place)

Comment: If you want an in-place sort then this is a duplicate

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this:

```
var orderedList = list.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Item1);
```

We use the `OrderByDescending` method in order we order from the biggest number to the smallest, and passing the lambda `x=>x.Item1`, we state the ordering would be done based on the first item of each tuple.

**Update**

If you want the above statement to be executed immediately and not using deferred execution -when the `orderedList` will be requested from someone else for 'consumption'-, you should try the following:

```
 var orderedList = list.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Item1).ToList();
```

Comment: And stick a .ToList() at the end to return a list

Answer (score 1):

Try using `List.Sort` with a comparer, in this case [`Int32.CompareTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.compareto%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var list = new List<Tuple<int,int,int>>();

list.Sort((x, y) => y.Item1.CompareTo(x.Item1));
```

Comment: This is clearly the best answer (unless the OP doesn't want to reorder the original list).

Answer (score 0):

Easy with Linq:

```
var list = new List<Tuple<int,int,int>>();

var ordered = list.OrderBy(t => t.Item1);
```

Comment: This sorts in ascending order

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a comparer when sorting it.