# Tuple or Sortedlist

Tags: c#, tuples, sortedlist

What is the 'benefit' except redundancy to use Tuple instead of SortedList.

My situation is that im comparing sets of 2 elements with a list together and do some data comparing and create new lists from that data(see below)

```
SortedList<KeyValuePair<string, string>, List<string>>
List<Tuple<<KeyValuePair<string, string>, List<string>>>
```

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668525/sort-listtupleint-int-in-place

Comment: Obviously, sorted list is sorted so the benefit is that it is sorted if you need to have item in a given order or you need to search an item based on its key.