# How to sort List of Tuples by DataTime where DataTime third element of Tuple?

Tags: c#

I have list:

```
var tupleList = new List<Tuple<int, int, DateTime>>();
```

How can I sort this list by DataTime?

Comment: [`List.Sort()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netcore-3.1)? `tupleList.Sort((a, b) => a.Item3.CompareTo(b.Item3));`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort List<Tuple<int, int>> in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668525/sort-listtupleint-int-in-place) The same question with different item type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Sort` and create comparer:

```
tupleList.Sort(Comparer<Tuple<int, int, DateTime>>.Create(
    (t1, t2) => t1.Item3.CompareTo(t2.Item3)))
```

Or create new list with LINQ:

```
tupleList = tupleList
        .OrderBy(t => t.Item3)
        .ToList();
```